# C#: Searching for a keyword in a txt file

Tags: c#

I have a problem reading a comma-delimited TXT file. This is what I am trying to do. I'm searching a text file for a keyword and then, when I've found the line containing that keyword, getting the whole line of comma-delimited keywords into a string array. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What code do you have that is not working?

Comment: Give us a sample of your txt file.

Comment: Give us some examples of what you want to read and how you're handling it now please!

Comment: Just looking at the related questions should give you enough hints of how to achieve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");

String line;
String[] array;

while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if (line.Contains("myString"))
   {
      array = line.Split(',');
   }
}

file.Close();
```

In the if part yo can save your comma separated strings to an array

Comment: What if the line contains "myStrings"?

Comment: than you have to search for line.Contains("myString,")

Comment: how to do the comma seperated part?

Comment: Good solution. If it contains "myStrings", he can manipulate the line as he wants.

Comment: @Cuba I guess that is acceptable if you can guarantee the format of the file.

Comment: @Dominique, start by exploring `string.Split` and possibly CSV parsing techniques.

Comment: awesome! got it. Thanks a lot folks. I must say, i am very very impressed with the response times on this forum. Wow!

Comment: @goalie you are right. the encoding of the text file is important too

Comment: @Cuba, please demonstrate the proper way to deal with `IDisposable` resources. This answer will be found and used by who knows how many people, *[show them the right way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).*

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - Given this is a snippet of code, I don't see that wrapping it in a using statement is necessary for this site. Further, calling Close() will release resources, so calling Dispose() isn't strictly required... nice, certainly, but not required.

Comment: @Pedro, the point is that `Close()` is not guaranteed to be called in this snippet. Further, answers here *should promote good habits and not reinforce bad ones*. We should not assume the reader knows about the proper way to deal with disposables. I know from my own past experience, I've been the novice user completely in the dark and developed untold amounts of bad habits as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're going to want to read the file line by line and check each of those lines for your string.  When you find it, you'll take that line and split it into an array.

```
string temp = "";
string[] list;
IO.FileStream file = new IO.FileStream("MyFile.txt", IO.FileMode.Open);
IO.StreamReader reader = new IO.StreamReader(file);

While (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    temp = reader.ReadLine();
    if (temp.Contains("myString")
    {
        list = temp.split(",");
        break;
    }
}
reader.close();
```