# C#: Search and replace txt line

Tags: c#, text-files

I am looking for a way to search a comma separated txt file for a keyword, and then replace another keyword on that exact line. For example if i have the following line in a big txt file:

```
Help, 0
```

I want to find this line in the txt (by telling program to look for the first word 'help') and replace the 0 with 1 to indicate that i have read it once so it looks like:

```
Help, 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Did your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279503/c-searching-for-a-keyword-in-a-txt-file) not get you far enough along down this path? It's the same problem as before, although now you've introduced output.

Comment: I have tried reading the line, storing it in an array and then writing to a new txt file with the 1 instead of the 0. But i would rather have a way to just deal with the existing file and do a replace operation there

Comment: Why write to a new text file? If your reading buffer is closed you can just write to the same file again :S

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a very bad idea to try and overwrite data in the same file: if your code throws an exception, you'll be left with a partially processed file; if your search target and replacement value have different lengths, you have to re-write the rest of the file. Note that these don't apply in your specific situation - but it's best not to let it become habit.

My recommendation:

1. Open both the input file and a temporary file (`Path.GetTempFileName`)
2. process and write each line ( `StreamReader.ReadLine`)
3. When finished with no errors, rename the original file to something like origFile.old
4. rename the temporary file to the original file name.

If something goes wrong, delete the temporary file and exit.  This way the original file is left intact in the event of an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the replacement "in place" (meaning you don't want to use another, temporary, file) then you would do so with a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33wz7kas.aspx).

You have a couple of options, you can [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) through the file stream until you find the text that you're looking for, then issue a [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write.aspx).  Keep in mind that `FileStream` works at the byte level, so you'll need to take character encoding into consideration. [`Encoding.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) will do the conversion.

Alternatively, you can search for the text, and note its position.  Then you can open a FileStream and just [`Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) to that position.  Then you can issue the `Write`.

This may be the most efficient way, but it's definitely more challenging then the naive option.  With the naive implementation, you:

- Read the entire file into memory ([`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx))
- Perform the replace ([`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx))
- Write it back to disk ([`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx))

There's no second file, but you are bound by the amount of memory the system has.  If you know you're always dealing with small files, then this could be an option.  Otherwise, you need to read up on character encoding and file streams.

Here's another SO question on the topic (including sample code): [Editing a text file in place through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104324/editing-a-text-file-in-place-through-c)